# Bing detect method and Jquery

Tags: ajax, jquery, bing, bing-api

since Google translate api will stop working i'm trying to implement some  jquery code to translate text, but i can't make it working
One simple example of this api is [here](http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/ajax.svc/Detect?appId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&text=A%20hola%20muchos)

As you can see the return result is a string with the language that is detected.
Τhis is my code, should i try a post/get method?
I'm really confused with this stuff

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/ajax.svc/Detect?appId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&text=A+hola+muchos",
        data: msg,
        success: function(msg){
            alert( msg);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have managed to make it work :)
For anyone who eve wants to use this try out:

```
var p = {};
p.appid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
p.text = t;
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Detect',
    data: p,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'oncomplete',
    jsonpCallback: 'ajaxTranslateCallback',
    success: function(data, status) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```